# Rendering not working?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I started working on a new project, and I tried to render the scene, and I haven't changed any thing that I normally would, yet this time, instead of the rendering and the little orange squares rendering the image, there's nothing, its just a standard blank image that appears as soon as clicking render??? this really confused me, any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: This is a really good question, that im still trying to figure out

Comment: Hi unfortunately that post didn't work for me, but I may be onto something....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i may know what your problem is, if you have been working with compositing, it may be a really easy fix. just go into your compositing panel and revise all of your nodes and make sure nothing looks out of place, if you cant see anything, connect the render to the output to get a direct render to see if its your alpha channels, if that doesn't work, then make sure to check your layers, there may be something there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OMG thank you! I feel so dumb now to such an easy fix! thanks for all of your help!

Comment: You're welcome, and remember to make sure to check some other websites as well... because this question was asked before